# Rearrage the div in html

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div in my php page and it is shown below

```
<div class="col-md-16" id="">
    <div class="textwidget">
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult)) { ?>
        <div style="margin-bottom: -15px; margin-right: 20px; background-color: #008086;">
            <img class="alignnone wp-image-401" src="uploads/2016/12/homa-1-300x199.png" alt="" width="56" height="37" style="margin-bottom: -19px;" />
            <span class="About-us-Description" style="color: #ffffff;"><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></span><hr>
    </div>
    <div class="textwidget">
        <?php
    $query1 = "Select * from rituals where ritualtypeid=".$row['ritualtypeid'];
    $queryResult1 = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query1);
    ?>
    <?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult1)) { ?>
        <div class="Homas">
            <a style="color: #000000;" href="">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <span class="what-we-offer" style="color: #000000;">
                    <?php echo $row1['Name'] ?>
                </span>
            </a><br />
        </div><?php } ?>
        </div><?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

It will display the results as

```
**Heading1**
  Content1
  Content2

**Heading2**
  Content3
  Content4

**Heading3**
  Content5
  Content6


 **Heading4**
  Content7
  Content8 so on
```

But actually what i want to display is

```
 **Heading1**    **Heading2**     **Heading3**
   Content1         Content3         Content5
   Content2         Content4         Content6

  ---------------------------------------------------
  **Heading4**
    Content7
    Content8   so on
```

After 3 div i need a line break and next the div should appear in the next line. How to do it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: So... twitter bootstrap, 12 wide.. and a row for 3 columns with a number of  4.. and define a new div for the next row?

Comment: are you using bootstrap ? "col-md-16" does that class exist ?

Comment: @AngryCoder Ofcourse not.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code really dosen't explain your output but anyways, if you are using twitter bootstrap then you need to give all the elements a class of `col-md-4` and wrap them in a `row-fuild` div. Something like this:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="col-md-4" id="" >
            <div class="textwidget"><?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult)) { ?>
                <div style="margin-bottom: -15px; margin-right: 20px; background-color: #008086;">
                    <img class="alignnone wp-image-401" src="uploads/2016/12/homa-1-300x199.png" alt="" width="56" height="37" style="margin-bottom: -19px;" />
                    <span class="About-us-Description" style="color: #ffffff;"><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></span><hr></div>
                    <div class="textwidget">
        <?php 
        $query1 = "Select * from rituals where ritualtypeid=".$row['ritualtypeid'];
        $queryResult1 = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query1);
    ?>  
             <?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($queryResult1)) { ?>
                    <div class="Homas"><a style="color: #000000;" href="">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> <span class="what-we-offer" style="color: #000000;"> 
                                <?php echo $row1['Name'] ?> </span></a><br />
                    </div><?php } ?>
                    </div><?php } ?>
               </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `class="col-md-16"` i don't think this class is available in bootstrap because bootstrap having 12 grid system. Try this below code this what exactly you are looking for:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
   <p> **Heading1**</p>
  <p>Content1</p>
  <p>Content2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
   <p> **Heading2**</p>
  <p>Content3</p>
  <p>Content4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
   <p> **Heading3**</p>
  <p>Content5</p>
  <p>Content6</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <p style="border-bottom:1px dashed #000;"> &nbsp;</p>
  
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
   <p> **Heading4**</p>
  <p>Content7</p>
  <p>Content8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
   <p> **Heading5**</p>
  <p>Content9</p>
  <p>Content10</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
   <p> **Heading6**</p>
  <p>Content11</p>
  <p>Content12</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```